# Where to find the gnuplot lua-tikz-terminal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

Where can I still download the `gnuplot` tikz terminal?

I keep winding up at broken links...

Or is there another alternative that makes `gnuplot` output tikz drawings?

Oh, and will I be able to get it working on mac os X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to avoid Fink and Macport I don't know anything about Homebrew.
I think that's the better way for you  is to compile : gnuplot. You need to install xcode but xcode is necessary with Homebrew too. Then you need to install lua. I'm not sure but it's preferable and this is easy. I think in the readme for the install you find something like 
`./configure --with-lua=yes`.
I make something like this on my Imac several months ago and then I have :

```
/usr/local/share/gnuplot/4.4/lua
/usr/local/share/gnuplot/4.4/lua/gnuplot-tikz.lua
```

And I can run this terminal

Remark : in the wiki of Homebrew there is a strange recommandation :

> We recommend you delete
>   `/usr/local/include` and
>   `/usr/local/lib`

There are another answers about `how compile gnuplot on a mac` but if you have a problem, you can find some helps here or on the net.

Comment: I used to exclusively `configure` and compile things from source as well---but I always keep forgetting which magical incantation I had to pass `configure` in order to get a given piece of software to compile. Homebrew lets me stash that knowledge in a Git repository so it is always available. The recommendations are there because some third party software living in `/usr/local/` can throw a wrench into `configure` scripts in odd ways (eg by being single-architecture when multi-arch is expected). Personally, I don't remove things until they cause a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using OS X, have you tried installing gnuplot through a package manger?

I use the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager and `brew install gnuplot` sets me up with a Lua-enabled version of gnuplot:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> set term tikz
Terminal type set to 'tikz'
Options are 'color dashed'
gnuplot> plot [-3.14:3.14] sin(x)
```

This produces:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 4.4p3 (Lua 5.1.4; terminal rev. 97, script rev. 96a)
%% Sun Apr 24 13:46:45 2011
\gpcolor{gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.196,0.616)--(1.376,0.616);
... plus many more lines that I have clipped for brevity
```

Hope this helps!

---

*Some other popular package managers for OS X are [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). I prefer Homebrew because it is integrated with [git](https://www.git-scm.com) and [GitHub](https://github.com/) which makes it easy to distribute my customizations to multiple computer systems*

Comment: I only knew Fink and MacPorts. Had macports installed and removing it right now to test Homebrew (don't know if this is needed, but I don't want multiple instances of the same app installed, this would lead to conflicts I guess). Homebrew looks very nice.